# What's the difference between ADD and COPY instructions in the Dockerfile

Tags: docker

Isn't clear to me, why there are two instructions for copying files into the Docker image described in the Dockerfile reference. There are [ADD](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#add) and [COPY](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#copy) and they seem pretty similar to me. Is there a practical difference between them? If not, which one is most used?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

According to [Best practices for writing Dockerfiles](https://docs.docker.com/engine/userguide/eng-image/dockerfile_best-practices/#add-or-copy),

> Although `ADD` and `COPY` are functionally similar, generally speaking,
>   COPY is preferred. That’s because it’s more transparent than `ADD`.

`ADD` can extract tar files and fetch remote URL files, although it's not very clear in the [official documentation](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#add). It's also important to state that,

> Because image size matters, using `ADD` to fetch packages from remote
>   URLs is strongly discouraged; you should use `curl` or `wget` instead.

```
COPY entrypoint.sh /srv/app/
ADD app.tar /srv/app/
```

So the general rule is as @derobert mentioned, use `COPY` unless you need `ADD` exclusive features.

Answer (score 6):

`ADD` performs a lot more “magic”: it fetches URLs and unpacks archives. That can be somewhat unexpected (especially the archive unpack). The official best practices guide recommends you [use COPY unless you need ADD's extra features](https://docs.docker.com/engine/userguide/eng-image/dockerfile_best-practices/#add-or-copy).

Comment: Thank you @derobert, I used your link as the base to a more developed answer.